# Multiple VirtualHosts files for subdomains in apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain, files

I'm new with apache2 and virtualHosts and all these things, I'm trying to set multiple subdomains, each in one file.

For example, I'll have

quentin-dommerc.com file in site-available :

```
<VirtualHost quentin-dommerc.com:80>
              DocumentRoot /var/www/
              ServerName quentin-dommerc.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and en.quentin-dommerc.com file in site-available :

```
<VirtualHost en.quentin-dommerc.com:80>
              DocumentRoot /var/www/en/
              ServerName en.quentin-dommerc.com
</VirtualHost>
```

But whatever the subdomain I go to, I'm always on quentin-dommerc.com :(

Note that I've a2ensite my files and they're well in site-enabled. I've also reloaded/restarted apache2. My CNAME are also set.

Comment: are the contents of the two folders /var/www/en and /var/www different? does the domain name itself change? if so, is there a redirect in /var/www/en/ that send the user to quentin-dommerc.com?

Comment: Yes they're differents. Nope, it is juste a subdomain of the root domain quentin-dommerc.com.

Comment: what does the domain name say when you go to the subdomain? does it redirect to the root domain?

Comment: Yep exactly, it redirects me to the root domain !

Comment: is this live? I just visited the subdomain and while it displayed the same content as the root domain, it did not redirect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your VirtualHost entries to use your ip address instead of domain name. e.g. if you ip address is 1.1.1.1

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
          DocumentRoot /var/www/
          ServerName quentin-dommerc.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
          DocumentRoot /var/www/en/
          ServerName en.quentin-dommerc.com
</VirtualHost>
```

You may also have to update your Listen lines to reflect using the ip address.